# How to recover private key from 2017 Parity wallet (non-standard BIP-39) recovery phrase?

Tags: wallets, openethereum

I have a 12-word recovery phrase for a 2017 era Parity wallet that I'd like to get access to.

I know its public key and I know the recovery phrase the wallet software provided me with upon setup. But I don't know the private key.

I have tried importing this recovery phrase as a seed-phrase in standard ETH wallet tools like Metamask or MEW, but one of the words ("dioxide") is apparently not in the standardized library of seed phrase words, so none of the modern ETH wallets will work.

I've now started to try to install ethkey (via Homebrew), hoping to use its "recover" function. But for some reason the installation of ethkey (paritytech/paritytech/ethkey) just doesn't finish.

Alas: How to proceed? I'd be happy for your suggestions.

I'd be fine with an online script that can figure out my private key from my parity recovery phrase as I'd be pulling off the funds asap and, worst-case it's not that much money to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

MEW stopped supporting parity seed words, you need to boot an older index up of MEW.